# Change javascript variable with a button

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I have a global Variable.

```
var w = 4;
```

and a function:

```
function do() {
    width = w;
    //make something
}
```

and now i want to change the variable w to 8 with a button.

```
<input type="button" onclick="do(w = 8;)" value="set 8">
```

that the function can work with w = 8 and forget the old w = 4!

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `w` in the proper scope:

```
var w = 4;

function do(width) {
    w = width;
    // ...
}
```

And then pass an argument to your function:

```
<input type="button" onclick="do(8)" value="set 8">
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that your code is wrong, almost from start to finish.  You really do need to read a book on the basic syntax of using Javscript.

That said, this will do what you asked for:

```
var w = 4; // Bad idea to have a global variable.  It is also unused.

function do(w) { // You pass a parameter here.
    var width = w; // no need for this because now you have a 'w'
    //make something
}


<input type="button" onclick="do(8)" value="set 8"> <!-- the value does nothing here -->
```